# Multi layered image parallax pure css

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have 3 images, first one is a transparent sun image, second a mountain image transparent and third a human character(transparent).

The first image should be in the deep back but should move, second should be fixed to bottom so the first image can hide behind it and when we scroll it, it should look like that sun is rising behind from mountain. For third image - that should be in foreground and move from down to up while we scroll.

I cannot adjust those images.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all make the parent div position as relative and their children position as absolute. now use top, left,right,bottom to position them.